# Windows 7 BSOD on boot

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I need help in troubleshooting or at least pointing me in the right direction as to how to troubleshoot a BSOD.

I was previously using my windows and it was working fine, I didn't install any new programs nor drivers and I was mainly using it to browse the internet.

Last night I left it on because I was downloading something, and when I woke up it had shut down, upon turning it on windows says the system has crashed and gave me the option to do startup repair or start normally.

Upon starting normally it would load the starting windows screen (the swirling dots into the windows logo), then blank out for a couple of seconds (which is normal operation before) and then for a second show the mouse but then the Blue Screem shows, which normally after the mouse loads the log-in screen shows

Here is the screen

[image]

Here are my system specs:
Windows 7 64 bit
Intel Core i3
4GB Ram
Toshiba Satellite L745

I tried startup repair and using chkdsk (which says its fine/or has corrected the errors) sfc /scannow (says everything is okay) and tried a system restore (restored but still BSOD).

Also, the laptop can also boot Ubuntu and it works fine with it. So I am able to at the very least access the files in the drives.

EDIT: I can't also boot in any safe mode option or any regular boot option...

EDIT: Here are the .dmp files and .evtx files if anyone can use a program to read them...Can you please tell me what program or driver is causing the issue, thank you
[.dmp files](http://mega.nz/#!m05DEIzL!6T4rHEy5MG2-fmjAhD2G1Bx9Ilx28tYJtGyrt9qsffs)
[.evtx files](https://mega.nz/#!mwYXhI4L!zo2DS7eWAzC8_Cn1dYcGQRjsTVHF44skATrQVOEAY7s)

Comment: Do you have SP1 installed? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2876900/fix-stop-error-0x000000f4-occurs-when-an-application-creates-a-process

Comment: I'm can't remember if I have one, and I can't even boot into windows even on any safe mode option....

Comment: The instructions on the screen tell you to bring it up in safe mode. Did you? If it does boot into safe mode, then run an analysis on the dump file. Get a copy of "whocrashed" from https://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed  and run it. It will make suggestions on what to do next.

Comment: I'm sorry as this should have been written before; but I already tried all safe mode options and they still show the BSOD screen...

Comment: OK, if safe mode is out, then your next option is recovery mode. From here you can try system restore, if that fails you can reinstall the OS. Safe mode would save you a lot of hassle if you could get it to come up. Personally, I would pull the hard drive out temporarily add it to another machine and verify that it is ok by looking at the SMART data, then copy that dump file to a working machine scan it and see what's up, before a complete re-install, but that's just me.

Comment: I already tried system restore and it didn't fix the issue...

The laptop dual-boots Ubuntu, I may try to get the SMART data from there. Is there a way to view crash details in my windows using Ubuntu?

Comment: _" Is there a way to view crash details in my windows using Ubuntu?"_ Not unless you can run WinDbg. But you can grab the dump file, zip it, post it on a file sharing site, and link to it. By the way that bugcheck code means "CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION - a process or thread crucial to system operation has unexpectedly exited or been terminated." In this case it's a process. But the only way to figure out which process, or why it might have died, is to examine the dump file with a Windows kernel mode debugger such as WinDbg.

Comment: (contd.) Ideally you should post C:\windows\memory.dmp , if it's there. Otherwise the most recent few .dmp files in C:\windows\minidump .

Comment: I just uploaded the .dmp files from both locations, do you also need the .evtx files?
https://mega.nz/#!m05DEIzL!6T4rHEy5MG2-fmjAhD2G1Bx9Ilx28tYJtGyrt9qsffs

Comment: the crash on 1/1 was caused by the HAL - the hardware abstraction layer the second crash on 1-16 has to do with thermal problems, something may be getting too hot. You should take some time and learn to do this yourself. In the meantime, make sure the fans are working and blow out any dust you can find.

Comment: So is there any fix I can do or is it done for...
I do know of a way to read those files but I can't boot into windows right now (not even a safe mode boot) and I am just using Ubuntu which I am dual booting (which runs fine, so I'm not so sure about the thermals... I mean it doesn't get that hot when just starting up)